# MongoDB query timing out even though I indexed the fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am running a query on a very large collection (500m documents) which is timing out sometimes (6 minutes) or takes very long (3-6 minutes).

I indexed all the relevant fields (no compound index): Tag, trophies, battleLogMonitorFrequency, profileRefreshedAt are indexed and the totalIndexSize is lower than 60% of my memory (45gb indexsize of 153gb which are available for mongodb).

```
const oneHour: number = 1000 * 60 * 60;
      const projection: {} = { tag: 1 };
      const filter: {} = {
        battleLogMonitorFrequency: interval,
        profileRefreshedAt: { $lt: new Date(snapDate.valueOf() - interval * oneHour) }
      };
const profileCursorTrophies: QueryCursor<IPlayerProfileModel> = PlayerProfile.find(filter, projection).sort({ trophies: -1 })
        .limit(50000).lean().cursor();
      await profileCursorTrophies.eachAsync(
        (profile: IPlayerProfileModel) => {
          outDatedProfileTags.push(profile.tag);
        },
        { parallel: 100 }
      );
```

**My question:**

Why does it take so long (that it even times out) until I get a sorted result? I was under the impression that indexing the fields I sort and filter on should be enough for that query?

**Edit:** Full query explain results: https://hastebin.com/ofixobasix.bash

**Edit 2:** Output of getIndexes(): https://hastebin.com/azayojokez.scala

**Edit 3:** After recommendations to use a compound index for my query, I noticed the results haven't changed at all. The query still takes a very long time to execute. See the following explain results: https://hastebin.com/ragixuqaci.bash

This index has been added:

```
    {
            "v" : 2,
            "key" : {
                    "battleLogMonitorFrequency" : 1,
                    "profileRefreshedAt" : 1,
                    "trophies" : -1
            },
            "name" : "battleLogMonitorFrequency_1_profileRefreshedAt_1_trophies_-1",
            "ns" : "dbname.playerprofiles",
            "background" : true
    }
```

Comment: I understand you have collection having 500m documents. How much data is expected to come out as result of your query?

Comment: I limit the results to 50k in this query and I expect 50k results quite often (1k is the default cursor set size I believe).

Comment: 50k seems to be good amount of data. Did you do `explain`? How many records are scanned ?

Comment: Here you can find the explain result, I am not sure where I can see the amount of scanned records: https://hastebin.com/vokaloqipu.bash

Comment: try `.explain("executionStats")` and see the `executionStats` section. It is quite self explanatory.

Comment: @AmitPhaltankar here they are: https://hastebin.com/xozitukale.bash . But I don't see anything wrong with that. It says it took ~21s but sometimes it seems to take a lot longer. Why does it take 21s in the first place, seems to be a lot too no?

Comment: Can you also provide the output of `getIndexes()` run against the same collection?

Comment: @PeteGarafano sure! Added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Here is how you went:*

You created compound index `{battleLogMonitorFrequency: 1, profileRefreshedAt: 1, trophies: -1}` and got into out of memory issue during sort.

```
errmsg: \"Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.\""
```

> I followed below steps to solve it.

---

**1 . Created a collection of 100m records**

```
db.myc.count()  > 100034080
```

My query looks like this:

```
db.myc.find({field1  : 1, field2: {$lt : 800}}).sort({field3 : 1})
```

The query should return back **38.9m records** (I know that's huge but I wanted to load test it)

---

**2. Then I created index `{field1 : 1, field2: 1, field3:1}`**

Executed query and got Out of Memory for Sort. Here, I was able to reproduce OP's issue.

(snippet of explain)

```
"executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : false,
        "errorMessage" : "Exec error resulting in state FAILURE :: caused by :: errmsg: \"Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.\"",
        "errorCode" : 96,
        "nReturned" : 0,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 19033,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 322639,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 322639,
        "executionStages" : {

            "inputStage" : {

                "inputStage" : {

                    "inputStage" : {

                        "indexName" : "field1_1_field2_1_field3_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                            "field1" : [ ],
                            "field2" : [ ],
                            "field3" : [ ]
                        },

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**3. (*Solution*) Changed the order of fields in index `{field1 : 1, field3: 1, field2:1}`**
Re-executed the query and this time I got my response. 
Also the `totalDocsExamined` and `nReturned` are actually same, which indicates that the index is used perfectly by Mongo Query Optimiser.

```
"executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 38901493,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 1571781,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 38902394,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 38901493,
        "executionStages" : {

            "inputStage" : {

                "indexName" : "field1_1_field3_1_field2_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "field1" : [ ],
                    "field3" : [ ],
                    "field2" : [ ]
                },

            }
        }
    }
```

Although, my query took very long time to execute but that is obvious as it is returning (unrealistic) 38.9m records. What I am more concerned about it did mongo use correct index? and the answer is YES.

---

**Explanation:**
The OP's query is a typical schenario of Mongo's `Equality, Range, Sort` issue. 
When there is an index over `equality field - range field - sort field`  Mongo use it only for the filter and not for sort. Hence the sort is performed in-memory.
To solve this we need to keep the range field at the end of compound index.

I found a [good article](https://dzone.com/articles/optimizing-mongodb-compound) to explain the scenario better.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I've also posted a different explain which was scanning a lot more documents and it also took a lot longer. Can you explain why MongoDB takes only one indexed field if all relevant fields are indexed? I was under the impression that MongoDB would consider all indexes (also if there are multiple fields involved) for a single query.

Comment: @kentor Sorry for my late reply. As per the mongo docs the index intersection was introduced only after 4.0. which version are you using? Also, try creating multi-field index using two of your search fields

Comment: I didn't know about MongoDB 4.0. I am using the latest public version which is 3.6 at the moment.

Comment: sorry it was my bad. Event 3.6 should support index intersection. May be the first index used `trophies` is cause of the problem. Try using compound indexes and/or `hint`

Comment: Unfortunately I am still stuck. Even after adding the compound index the execution time is horrible. What should I look for in the execution stats to figure out why this is happening? I noticed that it's examining lots of documents, but I am not sure WHY this is happening? I've updated the thread

Comment: You can check `indexUsed`. Did it pick the compound index?

Comment: I don't see an "indexUsed" field in the explain results? I have uploaded the explain result and edited a link into the question here.

Comment: @kentor it this (https://hastebin.com/ragixuqaci.bash ) your latest `explain` ? if you look into `winningPlan` you should see `indexUsed` while the compound index in the `rejectedPlans`. Just try using `hint` with your query.

Comment: It seems we are getting closer to the solution, now I get an error that the sort operation requires too much RAM. It says I can add an index to solve this. Obviously we added the index in advance so the question is why the index is not working. See this hastebin: https://hastebin.com/ihuwihuluc.sm . The compound index has been added and is returned on getIndexes(). I added the index with the `background` option, is that the reason maybe?

Comment: `background` option will just keep the collection unblocked while the index is being generated. Looks like you have multiple indexes but somehow mongo is not picking the most essential one, you can solve this by using the `hint` option. With this you can suggest mongo to use a particular index for query.

Comment: Somehow hastebin cut the first line. I actually used hint, that's why I am confused. Either I am using hint wrong or something is wrong with the index. See this ghostbin which contains the full first line where I am using hint: https://ghostbin.com/paste/wdpmm

Comment: Any ideas why this is happening @Amit Phaltankar ?

Comment: @kentor Just arrived at office thinking about this problem. The behaviour cannot be justified theoretically was planning to give it a practical shot. will update you how it goes.

Comment: @kentor can you please put couple of sample document from your collection. Just wanted to know the structure

Comment: @kentor I created a random collection of 50M records. Without index it used to take 30 seconds to return 43K sorted records. I added compound index and the time got reduced to 1.4 seconds. You should notice `totalDocsExamined` & `nReturned` are same. That indicates the indexes used at their best. Check https://hastebin.com/duvahojadu.swift Let me know where are you upto

Comment: Amit can you try to adapt the filter so, that it would still return ~30m documents which have to be returned sorted by a field? Because that's ltierally the case for me. Since you are just sorting on 40-50k documents (instead of millions) it wouldn't overflow the max size for unindexed fields anyways I think?

Comment: @kentor I think I am close to solve it. I created a collection with 100m records and created query which returns 38.9m records. Created compound index and got out of memory on SORT. Created second compound index and  this time I got output if 38.9m sorted records. I can see mongo used the index perfectly for all 3 fields and documents scanned vs returned is exactly the same. Only concern is it took 1500 seconds which I think is obvious for such huge data . Have a look https://pastebin.com/YWYsQ567. Let me know if this helps and I will update my answer with the snippets.

Comment: Can you explain why this second compound is needed for just one query? It takes some time for each index I add due to the amount of documents, but I will try it. It doesn't make any sense for me why this would work though, can you explain that?

Comment: You actually need only one index (the second one in my example). You have equality search on field `a`, range search on `b` and sort on `c`. If you create compound index `a:1, b:1, c:1`, Mongo use index for the search but not for sort. Hene sort is performed in-memory. That is why you got out of memory error in sort. 
Instead if you create index `a:1, c:1, b:1`, Mongo correctly use index for both search and sort operations. This is a typical issue with Mongo Indexing. Check `Equality, Range Query, And Sort` section [here](https://dzone.com/articles/optimizing-mongodb-compound)

Comment: Thanks that finally worked, thanks for the explanation as well, which is very important to me, so that I don't struggle a second time with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

According to the `explain()` output, the index chosen by the `mongod` is `profileRefreshedAt_1` and required scanning `408295390` keys. That is ~82% of the entire collection. This large result set then requires un-indexed matching to satisfy the `battleLogMonitorFrequency` clause. This means, each of the `408295390` keys returned by the `IXSCAN` needs to be matched by the `mongod` without the aid of an index, pulling each document off disk, into cache, to be evaluated.

Looking at the indexes available on the collection, I would suggest creating a compound index on `battleLogMonitorFrequency` and `profileRefreshedAt`. Depending on which field has fewer matches for your query, that should come first in the index. For example, given the following conditions:

- battleLogMonitorFrequency `$eq` 336 has 100,000 matches
- profileRefreshedAt `$lt` new Date("2018-04-29T00:00:00.000Z") has 100,000,000 matches

We would want to create an index of the form
`battleLogMonitorFrequency:1, profileRefreshedAt:1` since querying on `battleLogMonitorFrequency` first reduces the number of keys we are scanning in the `profileRefreshedAt` clause.

If the conditions are the other way around, then we would reverse the key ordering in the index. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/create-queries-that-ensure-selectivity/index.html for some more details.

Comment: Does that mean `mongod` can use only ONE index for ONE query? Because `battleLogMonitorFrequency` is also an index in my collection. Thanks a ton for your analysis on my explain query!

Comment: `mongod` _can_ do index intersection, but it isn't guaranteed to happen. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-intersection/index.html

Comment: After reading that article I believe that index intersection should work in my case? However the query seems to be problematic. Did I missunderstand the index intersection article?